# decomposition of hom-functors in a self-enriched category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory, hom-functor

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a self-enriched category (such as **Set**).

The Functor $\mathbb{C}(X, \mathbb{C}(Y,\_))$ is the same than the composition of functors $\mathbb{C}(X,\_) \circ \mathbb{C}(Y,\_)$.

In a similar manner, how can the functor $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}(X,\_), \mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}(Y,\_),\_))$ be rewritten as a composition of hom-functors?

Comment: Do you want $\mathbb C(\mathbb C(X, \_), \mathbb C(\mathbb C(Y, \_), \_)) (D) = \mathbb C(\mathbb C(X, D), \mathbb C(\mathbb C(Y, D), D))$?

Comment: @fauxefox Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Unless $\mathbb C$ is self-enriched, such as $\mathbf{Set}$, these expressions don't make sense.

Comment: @DerekElkins Indeed. The case of interest to me in **Set** but I would prefer an abstract solution for any self-enriched category. I have edited my question accordingly. Do you have an answer?